# App redirects to blank screen when opening modal in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in my app. But when the website behavior is to open a modal, the webview redirects me to a blank screen. I put logs in `onPageStarted` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, and saw that it doesn't fit in either method.

```
 webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webview.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webview.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
        webview.settings.allowFileAccess = true


        webview.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {
            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            override fun onCreateWindow(
                view: WebView?,
                isDialog: Boolean,
                isUserGesture: Boolean,
                resultMsg: Message
            ): Boolean {
                val newWebView = WebView(context)
                val webSettings = newWebView.settings
                webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

                // Other configuration comes here, such as setting the WebViewClient
                val dialog = Dialog(context!!)
                dialog.setContentView(newWebView)
                dialog.show()
                newWebView.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {
                    override fun onCloseWindow(window: WebView) {
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                })
                (resultMsg.obj as WebViewTransport).webView = newWebView
                resultMsg.sendToTarget()
                return true
            }
        })

        webview.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                webView.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    if(progressBar!=null)
                         progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }, 3500)

            }

        })
        webview.loadUrl(url)
```

I also tried to redirect it to the chrome client if it was going to open the modal, but as it doesn't load any new urls, I don't think it's overwriting the method